# Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 1: FROM requires either one or three arguments

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

This is the code I've written in my Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu: latest
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN apt update && apt install python -y
CMD python /app/main.py
LABEL color=red
```

I am getting this error
Error response from daemon: dockerfile parse error line 1: FROM requires either one or three arguments

I tried to build the image using the dockerfile by running this code

```bash
sudo docker build -t custom-python-image ./
```

Comment: `FROM ubuntu: latest` -> `FROM ubuntu:latest` ?

Answer (score 0):

As [@kamilcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9072753/kamilcuk) mentioned you had a space when specified the image tag

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN apt update && apt install python -y
CMD python /app/main.py
LABEL color=red
```

You can run it as you do:

```bash
sudo docker build -t custom-python-image .
```